# Counting one item per ID (query) using JoinInner

Tags: sql, zend-framework, join, count

This is my **tag** table:

```
post_id   tag        topic
  1      picture   entertainment
  1      camera    entertainment
  1      mobile    technology
  2      cable     technology
```

This is my SQL right now (Using Zend Framework):

```
   $select = $db->select();
   $select->from(array('t' => 'tags'), array('count(*)', 't.topic'))
   ->joinInner(array('p' => 'posts'),'p.post_id = t.post_id')
   ->where('p.status = ?', self::STATUS_LIVE)
   ->where('t.topic= ?', $options);

   return $db->fetchOne($select);
```

I want to count topics, selecting **just one** per **id**. In this case it will be:

```
entertainment: 1
technology: 2
```

My result right now is:

```
entertainment: 2
technology: 2
```

**This is the solution:**

```
$select = $db->select();
$select->from(array('t' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT post_id,topic FROM tags group by post_id,topic)')), array('count(*)', 't.topic'))
->joinInner(array('p' => 'posts'), 'p.post_id = t.post_id', array())
->where('p.status = ?', self::STATUS_LIVE)
->where('t.topic= ?', $options)
->group("t.topic");

return $db->fetchOne($select);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*),topic FROM (SELECT post_id,topic FROM tags GROUP BY post_id,topic) t GROUP BY topic;
```

Same query in zend :

```
$select = $db->select();
$select->from(array('t' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(SELECT post_id,topic FROM tags group by post_id,topic)')), array('count(*)', 't.topic'))
       ->group("t.topic");

$db->fetchAll($select);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it seems to work for some of the topics, I edited my question for more detail. Thanks.

Comment: I took me a while to understand that it was a nested query, thank you!